# Cannot publish to Azure Functions from Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, azure-functions, publish

Previously I was able to publish to Azure Functions from Visual Studio but recently I always get an error saying that publish encountered an error.  It directs to a log file the contents of which is as follows:

```
    System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Publishing failed.
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Model.DefaultPublishSteps.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<IsBuildCompletedSuccessfully>b__2()
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Model.DefaultPublishSteps.<DefaultCorePublishStep>d__23.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.<RunPublishTaskAsync>d__205.MoveNext()
    (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Publishing failed.

System.Exception: Publishing failed.
```

I have tried the following:

- Reset publish profile in Azure, create a new profile in Visual Studio and try publish again.  Still same error.
- Delete Function App in Azure and recreate it.  Get new publish profile into Visual Studio and try publish again.  Still same error.
- Upgrade Visual Studio 2019 to latest Version (16.2.5) and try publish again.  Still same error.

Note that I have a Azure website in the same solution and I can still publish that to Azure.

Comment: Yoo this happens for me too, but the function is published and will work fine with the changes that you made. It is just a visual studio bug

Answer (score 1):

I am very new to Azure functions but today I had a similar problem (maybe the same problem) and I found a workaround, so I hope it will work also for you.
Visual studio publishes the function by sending (upload) a zip file to azure. Unfortunately it seems VS sets a timeout to send this file, so if it is too big or your connection is too slow in upload the publishing fails because it doesn't finish before the timeout :(

There are other ways to send the zip without VS, if you want to learn details see the link below, otherwise TL;DR just follow my simple instructions already tested below the link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push

I used the curl command and it works for me, no timeout. You can try also powershell or AZ cli but curl is really easy, just be careful to get right uid/pwd the uid in my case was "$"+"project_name" 
here is an example, replace params with yours

```
curl -X POST -u your_username:your_password --data-binary @"your_zip_path" https://your_project_name.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy
```

Be patient and wait till the end the upload, there is no progress bar, see network activity, if it's sending data the upload is in progress. You find all the params inside the publishing file you can download from azure, they are also in VS. For the zip file you can use the one VS wasn't unable to deploy, Vs does not remove it, in my case it was under the proj dir in obj\Release\netcoreapp2.1\PubTmp

P.S I have WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE set to 1 this setting is recommended to 1 by many ms doc, so be careful changing to 0, you might have side effects.

Comment: Thank you for this.  It is probably the same problem as what I am having as the problem is sporadic, which would indicate it has something to do with connection speed and timeout

Comment: @SteveFarnaby you're welcome. Probably you are at the edge. Add more code/nuget that increase zip size and the problem will be permanent. If you want a quick fix you might use a faster connection. I temp. swapped to my 4G hotspot (48Mbits upload) and the VS publish completed in a snap with no errors :) while ADSL was always error. Also you can publish from an azure VM (in same region as function app) which has super fast connection (Azure to Azure). Take care ;)

Answer (score -1):

If **`WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE`** is set as 1 it could cause issue with depoyment from visual studio:

Open the Azure portal and check if this is the case, if yes then set it as 0. It should work.

Here is the supporting [link](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1108)

Hope it helps, if not please share the code base will try to repro at my end.

Comment: I have tried the above but still get the same publish failure.

Comment: Anyone else got an answer to this? I still have a similar issue.

Answer (score -1):

For me it was failing to deploy to V3, but worked for V2